# Scala-overriding variable value from trait

Tags: scala

I have a scala code from an open source library that looks like this:-

```
//somewhere in the open source code
trait A
{
val v1=callToSomeFunc()

def usefulFunc1() {}
def usefulFunc2() {}
}
```

Required: I am inheriting the trait and I don't want my class in any situation to call 'callToSomeFunc()' when inheriting the trait A but want to use usefulFunc1() and usefulFunc2() of trait A.

Could you kindly help?

(For those from Spark background, I am facing multiple sparkcontexts error because the open source library that I am inheriting from defines a sparkcontext which is definitely not something I want to use)

Thanks

Comment: What does this have to do with Apache Spark?

Comment: @JoeC, edited the question

Comment: can you share the code giving you problems?

Comment: Also can you explain what exactly is the problem? does callToSomeFunc create a spark context?

Comment: Please review our [SO Question Checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer.

Comment: Your question is still not a question about Apache Spark.  Yes, you may be using Spark as part of your project, but it appears that your question is fundamentally about Scala.  Thus the Apache Spark tag is inappropriate.

Comment: @JoeC removed spark tag, kindly remove  hold on the question. Thanks

Comment: Even if I had the power to remove the hold, I would not do so.  Your question still does not make clear the problem you want to solve, and why you think you want to solve it.  You should consider creating a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which clarifies your problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can override a val inherited from a trait.

```
override val v1 = somethingElse
```

No change in the open source required.

[Scala Cookbook from Safari](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/scala-cookbook/9781449340292/ch08s03.html)

Code that works for me in Scala 2.11.8

```
object TestIt extends App {
  val jump = new TestIt
  jump.sayWhat()
}
trait base {
  val dontGoChangin: String = "dontGoChangin"

  def sayWhat() = {println(dontGoChangin)}
}
class TestIt extends base{
  override val dontGoChangin: String = "toTryToPleaseMe"
}
```

Comment: As I understand, `I don't want my class in any situation to call 'callToSomeFunc()' when inheriting the trait A` he will not override it, only protect it's accessibility?

Comment: you can't reassign to val.

Comment: Did you take a look at the referenced article?

Comment: Yes you can reassign a val's trait with override. @WillD is correct

Comment: Is it the call that's the problem, or the fact that the v1 reference is incorrect?

Comment: @WillD , the line of code is override val spark=new MasterTest().spark where it throws the error 'override modifier not allowed here' and wrong value declaration

Comment: I've included some code above which works for me. What version of Scala are you running?

Comment: This would not work. the original value would still be constructed (and therefore its side effects would occur). You can check this by replacing the dontGoChangin definition to print something in each class before setting the value. When you do new, the original value would still run its course and the side effect would occur.

Comment: Hence my question above.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `private[this] val v1=callToSomeFunc()` to narrow the scope for your `v1` to only inside the trait. No class extending this trait will have access to it.

Comment: That is an OK solution but not the best as now I need to edit the code from the open source library.

Comment: Well, when you want to prohibit any class extending `trait A` to call the trait's method / field, but it's not your trait, there is no way for you to achieve this.